# GAMS remaining entries skipped

Tags: error-handling, compilation

In the GAMS output file, end of the equations some part may not be seen. It states that " REMAINING 25 ENTRIES SKIPPED" however I need to see all of the equations and explanation about them. How can I find the skipped entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `Limrow=n`, with '`n`' the number of entries you would like to see.

You can find more information in the following links:

[equation listing](https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fuserguides%2Fmccarl%2Fequation_listing_1.htm) en [Limrow option](https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fuserguides%2Fmccarl%2Flimrow.htm)

By default, GAMS will only show 3 equations.